# Determine if an array is decreasing-increasing O(log(n)) and find the "switch" value

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I'm trying to determine whether an array is decreasing first then increasing.
Also I need to find out the value when the pattern changes from ascending to descending which would be the min value in the arrays

Let's say for example I have the following array:

[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 12, 13, 22, 31, 40, 59, 78]

and this one

[-1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]

Edit: for simplicity you can assume the values won't be repeated like the first example I showed you

I mainly want to write a program that takes O(logn) time.
I'm trying to use binary search and this is what I have come up with. The input to the function is a sorted list or an descending-ascending list. That can have repeated values as shown in the above examples

```
    def find_middle(ls):
        start = 0
        end = len(ls) - 1
        idx = -1
        while start < end:
            mid = start + (end - start) // 2
            middle = ls[mid]
            if ls[mid-1] <= middle and middle > ls[mid+1]):   
                return middle
            elif ls[mid-1] < middle:
                start = mid         
            else:
                end = mid
     return idx
```

Sorry for the messy code, I have tinkered with it alot and at this point I've just given up on finding a solution.

If the array is JUST decreasing or increasing, I want the function to return -1.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: To clarify are you trying to find the min value in log(n) time for the for two types of array patterns: 1) descending, then ascending (your 1st case shown), and 2) purely ascending  (your 2nd case shown)?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Please [edit] your code to clarify the question, and fix the indentation of your code. *How* is the list sorted? A list cannot be numerically sorted, increasing *and* decreasing at the same time. Are your lists always just ascending, descending, ascending-descending or descending-ascending? Can your lists be, for example, ascending-descending-ascending? Your first array has parts that are constant, does this also occur in your target data (is the data *strictly* ascending/descending)?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to detect whether the array is descending then ascending and if it's only ascending then I would like to return -1. @MelvinWM no

Comment: What makes you think this can be done with binary search, or ``O(log n)``? For example, how do you expect binary search to work in the case of ``[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]``?

Comment: Hmm, that it is a corner case, but assuming it would generally be not repeated that much, is a O(logn) possible? This is actually part of challenge question that I'm trying to solve, it states that it can be done in O(logn). The array I showed above is similar to your example although not as extreme. I came up with it, and is one of the reasons why I can't do this as well

Comment: If this is a challenge question, please accurately provide its task and constraints. There is little point in trying to solve a second-hand description of a challenging problem.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi--[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1] is different from the patterns he mentions.  This pattern is increasing then decresing.

Comment: @DarrylG The description says "the value when the pattern changes from ascending to descending", which of course is contradictory to "which would be the min value in the arrays". Since the only change is swapping ``>`` and ``<``, I assume a solution that works for either variant is sufficient.

Comment: @DarrylG The answer you deleted was wrong as MisterMiyagi showed :).

Comment: The challenge description was pretty vague, I gave you more detail than what it actually states. Maybe it's simpler than I think, can you provide a solution that doesn't consider duplicates? I'll edit the post to reflect that

Comment: @Eesa It is really easy if you require that there are no duplicates at all in the list, it is a fun problem that you would gain from solving. If you tried solving it assuming duplicates before, try again assuming without duplicates.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi provided a good counter example, although it probably should be [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], since the assumption is that *"The input to the function is a sorted list or an descending-ascending list."*

Comment: *"but assuming it would generally be not repeated that much, is a O(logn) possible"*: what is "not much"? Really, that is killing the question. It should have precise requirements, not vague terminology.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll definitely try myself first. Edit: turns out I can't actually delete so I'll leave it, solve it on my own then come back for the solution. @trincot: I was guessing the challenge requirements as the details of it were very sparse.

Comment: @ MelvinWM--that's why I deleted my answer when I realized my solution and the original code it was based upon is only for non-repeating values.

Comment: @Eesa--are you sure your arrays have repeating values?  In variations of this question I find on the internet the arrays don't have repeating values as you have with `[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, ...]`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example there is repetition. Without repetition this is easy. Check the values at three different indices. Calling these x, y, and z, we can see that the boundary can only be in of of the three intervals (x,y), (y,z), (z,x). So if we look at the ordering of these pairs, either 2 will be ascending and 1 descending or the reverse. The majority matches the array. Then, you can use binary search to find the boundary. This is O(log n)

With repetition this requires (in the worst case) linear time. A bad example is where you have an array where all but 2 elements are identical. In this case it is O(n) just to find the different elements. In general, with repetition the same algorithm applies but you have the added work of finding different elements.